# pl sql trigger update column value when found specific number in same table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I want to create pl sql trigger that update column value when found the 8 . all other things remain same in table.
my code is below but its not working

```
create or replace trigger Update_Hour
  before UPDATE of hour ON register

     for each row
    declare
      -- local variables here
    begin
      if :new.hour  = 7 then
         :new.hour := 8 ;
      end if;
    end Update_Hour;
```

Comment: [Read](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) about trigger syntax.

Comment: i read it ... above trigger not working any other solution pls

Comment: Does it give an error, or just do not do that you want ? The syntax of your trigger is ok.

Comment: Define - *"not working"* ...

Comment: it give no error and compile successfully  but not changing column value from 7 to 8.

Comment: The syntax of the trigger seems fine - so if you are hoping to get any help here you should provide more information such as your table structure, your update statement - the end result....

Comment: thank you for all of you for comments ... i think this trigger working for new coming values, not for the old value that are already in the column ... they need to be updated manually.

Comment: Trigger works for records which are being updated, creating trigger doesn't affect to rows in table, Trigger fires on DML statement, so it will work if try to update any record in table, to update existing records according to new logic you need to it manually.

Comment: `I want to create pl sql trigger that update column value` update to what value ?

Answer (score 0):

> "i think this trigger working for new coming values, not for the old value that are already in the column ... they need to be updated manually."

So what you need is:

```
update  register
set hour = 8
where hour = 7
/
```